# Why do some Reports dont show data despite the ID to select the row exist?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I got two Reports which obviously should display some data.

I have one parameter-field to select the data to display. I only got 5 rows in my database atm with IDs from 4000 to 4006. If the value of the parameter-field is 4003 everything works fine and the two reports are displayed correctly. If I use any of the other IDs, the reports don't show any data as if the ID wouldn't exist.

Then I got some other reports that work with all IDs. All of the reports above already worked fine.

I am new in Crystal Reports, so I don't know, how to debug since, there is no option.

- Database seems to work fine, since some reports are working.
- The parameter-value seems to be correct, since it gets displayed correctly.
- The select operation should be correct. Both SQL-Statements are the same except the different IDs and there is only one "where" statement which use the id to select the row.
- Selected IDs exist.

Would be great, If someone can help me.

Comment: Try executing your select statements directly from SQL Management Studio inserting all the parameters.  Do you get data then?

Comment: mmh no the data isnt there either

Comment: If you can post the query, maybe someone can help you find some issues that could occur with it.

Comment: i think the problem is the connection between the tables. its all inner join so if there is no matching row in one of the tables there is no data displayed.

Comment: Are you aware about inner / outer joins in sqlserver? so I suggest something.

Comment: Yes i am aware of them. The Problem is that CR is using inner join AS standard connection unless you specificate it otherwise after that. When i added a New table to my report there was no match except the one with the ID 4003. so that the report was working basicly was just luck. Going to check the result with left join when i am at work and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comments. The problem was the connection between the tables created by CR. When creating a connection it is an INNER JOIN automaticly. But what i needed was a LEFT JOIN. So i had to edit the connection after i created it.

That 4003 was displayed was just luck after i added a new Table.